# Use conditional places in setf

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Lets say I have two variables and I want to set the variable with lower value to nil.

Is it possible to make it work this way?

```
(setf a1 5)
(setf a2 6)  
(setf
  (if (< a1 a2) a1 a2)
  nil
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to do something close to this, you can use `(setf (symbol-value var) ...)`:

```
> (defparameter a1 5)
> (defparameter a2 6)
> (setf (symbol-value (if (< a1 a2) 'a1 'a2)) nil)
> a1
nil
> a2
6
```

To get a syntax closer to the one in your question, you can define an `setf-expander`for `if`:

```
(defsetf if (cond then else) (value)
     `(progn (setf (symbol-value (if ,cond ,then ,else)) ,value)
              ,value))
```

Then you can write `(setf (if (< a1 a2) 'a1 'a2) nil)`

However, the best way of writing the code is probably to do it straight forward, using an `if` with `setf` forms in both branches:

```
(if (< a1 a2) 
    (setf a1 nil)
    (setf a2 nil))
```

Comment: AFAIR, defining SETF for standard functions/macros/special operators is not allowed by CL specification.

Comment: @monoid You are partially right. Section 11.1.2.1.2 says that the consequences of defining set expanders for symbols in the COMMON-LISP package is _undefined_.

Comment: OK, it is not "not allowed", it is "you shouldn't" :)

Comment: Thank you, sure it is more clever do put `setf`s into `if`... but in some cases this may be more readable/easier :)

Answer (score 0):

No, because that `if` form is not a *place* and thus not `setf`able.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not very useful by itself, you might want to regard this as a little hint:

```
(defun new-values (x y)
  (if (< x y) (values nil y) (values x nil)))

(setf a1 5)
(setf a2 6)  
(setf (values a1 a2) (new-values a1 a2))
```